# How to remove Ghost Lines drawn in qgraphicsview

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene, qpainter

I am trying to make a simple program in which I have added a qgraphics scene and in this I have added a QGraphicsRectItem. I have implemented mouse press event, paint event, bounding rect. Now I have drawn a point on one side of rectangle because there can be multiple rectangle I can drop on screen so just to differentiate between them of different color. Now I can move my rectangle inside graphics seen and can increase the size of rectangle by moving it's one side at a time. The problem that I am facing is when I trying to draw point on one side of rectangle at the time of moving it, it leaves traces on graphics scene. can I remove the ghost lines?

Answer (score 3):

This happens either because your boundingRect method isn't correct, or because you forgot to call prepareGeometryChange before making changes that affect the boundingRect result. Your boundingRect needs to include space for line widths, for example; that's a common mistake.